# How do I overcome a "function is not defined" error when loading an external .js file?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I'd like to create a JS plugin (with ES6) so that it can be called from an HTML file, like this:

```
<div id="emails-box"></div>
<script src="emails-box.js"></script>
<script>
   const container = document.querySelector('#emails-box')
   EmailsBox({container, ...options})
   //some code
</script>
```

and it can be used independently.

What the EmailsBox will do is to take the container and add a children div with a box to store a bunch of emails.

I've tried to do this for 2-3 days, but everytime I try to load the .js file, I get a:

```
EmailsBox is not defined
```

I'm getting desperate. Could you someone give me some light? Thanks!

**EDIT**: In my emails-box.js file, I could have something like this:

```
var EmailsBox = function(obj){

   console.log("EmailsBox called")
   // some code

   return true;

}
```

Comment: can you post any content in `emails-box.js`?  probably you are not adding EmailsBox to global scope.

Comment: *How do I overcome a “function is not defined” error* - define the function - since you haven't shown where/how that function is defined, chances are you haven't defined that function

Comment: that is how we load jQuery and we can always use `$` after that... isn't it true that the external JS file will be downloaded and executed, before subsequent DOM html code or <script> tag is processed?

Comment: I edited my question with a sample of the .js file would be. It would be without jquery.

Comment: "In my emails-box.js file, I could have something like this:" yeah, but what do you *actually* have? Because the code you posted works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Worked fine for me. Make sure that emails-box.js is in the same folder as index.html and the name matches the one you're linking to. [working setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZT7p.png)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the file path of your .js file is referenced wrong. So first make sure that you referenced file right. If it is, then try to define function like don't assign it to variable, it might not be defined on load page.

```
function EmailsBox(obj){
    // some code
}
```

And if you really need it assigned to variable try using ready function.

```js
var EmailsBox = function(obj){

   console.log("EmailsBox called")
   // some code

   return true;

}
```

```html
<script>
(function() {
    EmailsBox({container, ...options})
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling the function, make  sure `options` variable is defined.
So that instead of calling:

```
EmailsBox({container, ...options});//when options is not defined,
```

define options first and then call the EmailsBox function like so:

```
var options = 'hello'; //for example
EmailsBox({container, ...options});
```

If your emails-box.js file is properly referenced, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that the problem with your source but if its because its not loading which would be weird then try using js to load the script if this doesn't work its wrong for sure and you should check it is right

```
var source = 'source here to script file';
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function () {
    //what you want to do with this script
};
script.src = source();

document.head.appendChild(script);
```